# How to change logging levels for executors?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, log4j, spark-streaming

The default logging level for all classes executed by Spark executors seems to be `INFO`. I would like to change it to `DEBUG`, or `WARN`, etc. as needed.

I'm using Spark Streaming 1.3.1 but will switch to 1.4 soon.

I have the following line in the shell script that submits the Spark Streaming job:

```
export SPARK_JAVA_OPTS="-Dlog4j.configuration=file:./log4j.properties"
```

This allows me to change logging level for the classes running in driver, but not in the executors.

How can I control logging for classes that are run by executors?

Note: We are not running on Yarn. We're starting our own Spark cluster on EC2.

Note: Ideally, we would like to change logging level while Streaming process is still running. If that's not possible, at least we should be able to change some properties file. Recompiling code & redeploying is NOT an option.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** Change `conf/log4j.properties` to appropriate levels and distribute the file to workers.

You may have some luck with `--files` command-line option for `spark-submit` when you submit your Spark applications. It lets you change logging levels per application. It's just a guess as I didn't try it out yet.